# Why is it necessary to use the friend modifier for overloading the * operator in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend-function

I have decided to implement the matrix operations as an exercise during my C++ studying. I have chosen the approach based on the templated class (to avoid dynamic memory allocation) and operators overloading

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, uint8_t ROWS, uint8_t COLUMNS>
class Matrix {
    public:
        T array[ROWS][COLUMNS];
        
        Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> operator+(const Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> & m) const{
            Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> result;
            
            for(uint8_t row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
                for(uint8_t column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++){
                     result.array[row][column] = array[row][column] + m.array[row][column];
                }
            }
            
            return result;
        }
        
        Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> operator-(const Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> & m) const{
            Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> result;
            
            for(uint8_t row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
                for(uint8_t column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++){
                     result.array[row][column] = array[row][column] - m.array[row][column];
                }
            }
            
            return result;
        }
        
        template<uint8_t N>
        Matrix<T, ROWS, N> operator*(const Matrix<T, COLUMNS, N>& m) const{
           Matrix<T, ROWS, N> result;
           
           for(uint8_t row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
               for(uint8_t column = 0; column < N; column++){
                   result.array[row][column] = 0;
                   for(uint8_t element = 0; element < COLUMNS; element++){
                       result.array[row][column] += array[row][element]*m.array[element][column];
                   }
               }
           }
           
           return result;
        }
        
        friend Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> operator*(double k, const Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> & m){
            Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> result;
            
            for(uint8_t row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
                for(uint8_t column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++){
                     result.array[row][column] = k*m.array[row][column];
                }
            }
            
            return result;
        }
        
        
        
        friend Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> operator*(const Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> & m, double k){
            Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> result;
            
            for(uint8_t row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
                for(uint8_t column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++){
                     result.array[row][column] = k*m.array[row][column];
                }
            }
            
            return result;
        }
                
        void print(){
            for(uint8_t row = 0; row < ROWS; row++){
                for(uint8_t column = 0; column < COLUMNS; column++){
                    std::cout << "[" << (int)row << "]" << "[" << (int)column << "]: " << (double)array[row][column] << std::endl;
                }
            }
            std::cout << std::endl; 
        }
};
```

I have encountered that whenever I remove the `friend` modifier from the overloaded `*` operator for the multiplication the matrix by the scalar the compilation process fails with following error messages:

- Matrix.h:65:34: error: 'Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS>::operator*(double, const Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS>&)' must have either zero or one argument
  65 |         Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> operator*(double k, const Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> & m){
- Matrix.h:80:34: error: 'Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS>::operator*(const Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS>&, double)' must have either zero or one argument
  80 |         Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> operator*(const Matrix<T, ROWS, COLUMNS> & m, double k){

Please can anybody tell me why the `friend` modifier is necessary?

Comment: With `friend`, you declare/define a free function. Without, it is a member method.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you for your response. I am sorry but I still don't understand. Why is it necessary to have the operators for the multiplication by scalar declared as a free functions?

Comment: `operator*(double, const Matrix&)` need to be free function, as for method, `*this` would be the first argument. `operator*(const Matrix& m, double k)` doesn't need to be free function, but must be written `operator*(double k) const` then. (and to respect the symmetry, we tend to use free function here too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For binary operation `XXX`, such as `lhs XXX rhs`,

Free function syntax would be `Ret operator XXX(const LHS&, const RHS&)`
(When **defined** within a class, it should be `friend`)

For member method of LHS, it would be `Ret LHS::operator XXX(RHS) const`
(when **defined** within the class, `LHS::` should be omitted)

**With `friend`, you declare/define a free function. Without, it is a member method.**

To handle `myDouble * myMatrix`, you need free function (`friend Matrix operator*(double, const Matrix&)`)

To handle `myMatrix * myDouble`, you might use free function or method. For symmetry with above case, using free function is preferred. (so `friend Matrix operator*(const Matrix&, double)` or `Matrix operator*(double) const`).